# Modifying API script to stop while loop when counter > x in Python?

Tags: python, api

it is my first time posting here so forgive me if my question is not up to par. As part of my job duties, I have to run API scripts from time to time though I really only have a basic understanding of python.

Below is a while loop:

```
hasMoreEntries = events['has_more'];
while (hasMoreEntries):
    url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team_log/get_events/continue"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer %s' % aTokenAudit,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    data = {
        "cursor": events['cursor']
    }

    r  = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    events = r.json()
    hasMoreEntries = events['has_more'];

    for event in events['events']:
        counter+=1;

print 'member id %s has done %s activites' % (memberId, counter)
```

From my understanding, the while loop will continuously count events and add to the counter. Because some users have too many events, I was thinking of stopping the counter at 5000 but not sure how to do so. Would adding an if/else somewhere work?

Comment: if I've understood your problem statement right, `while(hasMoreEntries  and counter<=5000)` should be your condition will do!

Comment: Btw `counter += len(events['events'])` is better than a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Because you already increased the `counter` at the end of while, you can just only need to check the value of `counter` before each loop iteration. And based on comments of [soon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532460/soon) and [Keerthana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039394/keerthana-prabhakaran), here is my suggestion (I use the `get()` method just to avoid KeyError):

```
has_more_entries = events.get('has_more', None)
while (has_more_entries and counter<=5000):
    url = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/team_log/get_events/continue"

    headers = {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer %s' % aTokenAudit,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    data = {
        "cursor": events['cursor']
    }

    r  = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
    events = r.json()
    has_more_entries = events.get('has_more', None)

    if events.get('events', None):
        counter += len(events['events'])
```

You can also take a look at the PEP8 coding style in Python [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pep-8-coding-style-guide-python/) if you're interested

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check that the counter is less than your maximum that you want it to get to in your while condition. e.g:

```
while hasMoreEntries and counter<=5000:
    <snip>
```